# Read Password Protected Excel Files Using OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an Excel file which is password protected.
I am using OpenXml to read the excel files.

As shown in the below code snippet, there is no overload/ Optional Parameter to specify Password.

```
_document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(_stream, false);
```

I don't see any provision to read the password protected files.

**Is there any way to read the password protected Excel Files in c# using OpenXml.**

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you cannot [using password protection doesn't not generate an Office Open XML file; you get a file in binary file format. The Open XML SDK does not work with the binary file formats.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a0863c56-791d-42e6-934c-ad79aef129c7/use-open-xml-sdk-with-files-open-xml-protected-password-for-read?forum=oxmlsdk)